# Error in final launch sequence Failed for OpenOCD (Olimex) for ARM (STM32fxx)

Tags: gdb, arm, microcontroller, stm32, openocd

I am using openOCD in eclipse for the arm STM32F10x series and after writing the whole code and  building everything without error in the program, I am going to Debug it and I am getting the following error after completion of 99% of the process:

> Error in final launch sequence   Failed to execute MI command:
>   -exec-run   Error message from debugger back end:   Error creating process

The following error is generated and I am not able to debug my program. 
so please help me for this problem

Comment: this question is a better candidate at [electrical engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange. you might get better answers.

Comment: Moreover don't duplicate questions on several sites : http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/59835/error-in-final-launch-sequence-failed-for-openocd-olimex-for-arm-stm32fxx

Comment: This is a gdb error (the debugger you are using with eclipse). Do you manage to debug other projects normally?

Comment: I ran into this, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39989603/1161906

Answer (score 0):

This is a gdb error (the "back-end here refers to the gdb backend, in opposition with the front-end which is integrated with Eclipse). You need to give more information about your configuration, from what you said you are using Eclipse with openOCD and GDB. Did you compile openOCD correctly for your target? Which operating system are you using?

It also seems that you are confused about openOCD, openOCD is a program which does the JTAG communication with your target (in your case through the "Olimex", I assume you mean the Jtag Key from Olimex?). Once OpenOCD is launched and function correctly you can use GDB to debug your target.