# stm32l0: Failed to execute MI command. Error erasing flash with vFlashErase packet

Tags: eclipse, stm32

I'm using a Nucleo STM32L031 with AC6 STM32 workbench (eclipse).

I write my application and go to debug mode, everthing was working well until I add another function in my application. I notice that when I remove/comment the "*new_function*", the software can go to debug mode again. However when I add the "*new_function*" to the code and go to debug, an error occurs and it cannot go to debug mode.

```
Error: Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
load C:Project_STM32L031K6-Nucleo\\Debug\\Project.elf 

Error message from debugger back end:
Error erasing flash with vFlashErase packet
Error erasing flash with vFlashErase packet
```

This error does not occur only for this specific "new_function", but also for other functions e.g TIM21_Init() generated by STM32Cube.

I tried to search for the solution, but couldn't find it.

Thanks
Bien

Comment: I have similar issues running some code I am completely unfamiliar with (haven't written it myself). If I understand your question correctly, this would imply some bug in the code I'm running? Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

In my case (stm32f429) changing this option helped:
[image: option to change]

Answer (score 3):

This is an OpenOCD issue, not a problem with your code. I got this issue when the debugger command file was referring to a "stlink-v2-1" but what I actually have is an "stlink-v2". I'm using the STM32F0 Discovery board.

I believe the Nucleo board has the "stlink-v2-1" so you might have the opposite problem as me. Check to make sure that the setting under "Run menu > Debug Configurations > Debugger > OpenOCD setup" is set to the correct debugger.

[image]

If a debug configuration file is being used (the "use default script" or "use local script" option is selected) open that file and look for a line like:

```
source [find interface/stlink-v2.cfg]
```

In my case the project wizard had created a template that was referencing stlink-v2-1. Changing it to the above fixed the problem.

**UPDATE:**

I also got this problem when Eclipse crashed and left OpenOCD running in the background. Run

```
$ ps aux | grep openocd
```

And if you see an instance of OpenOCD running when the debugger is not, kill it.